# Can not get data persisted in Room database unless ram is cleared

Tags: android, android-room

I have a Main Activity that loads data of coupons stored in Room database

Initially the data is clear , then there is a new Activity that adds a coupon to the database after ensuring that this coupon not already used then closes all activities and open a new instance of the Main Activity to load coupons

storing the coupons work fine, but when the new instance of the Main Activity starts again, it tells that there is no coupon, when I navigate to the add Coupon activity and try to use the same coupon, it tells me that the coupon already exists

Which means the Main Activity can not load data of the coupons inserted while the Add Coupon Activity can

Closing the app and relaunching it does not solve the problem

Clearing the RAM solves the problem and the Main Activity Loads data successfully

How to resolve this problem

This is the Main Activity file

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FloatingActionButton addCoupon;
    MaterialTextView noCouponText;
    RecyclerView termsRecyclerView;
    MaterialTextView address;

    List<CouponEntity> coupons=new ArrayList<>();
    List<TermEntity> terms=new ArrayList<>();
    public static List<TermEntity> allLoadedTerms=new ArrayList<>();
    public static int lastTermLayer;
    public boolean backPressed=false;

    TermViewModel termViewModel;
    CouponViewModel couponViewModel;

    void initialise(){
        addCoupon=findViewById(R.id.addCoupon);
        noCouponText=findViewById(R.id.no_coupon);
        address=findViewById(R.id.address);
        termsRecyclerView=findViewById(R.id.termsRecyclerView);
        termsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,1));
        lastTermLayer=1;

        couponViewModel=ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(CouponViewModel.class);
        termViewModel=ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(TermViewModel.class);
    }

    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                initialise();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        configureCoupons();
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private void configureCoupons() {
        coupons=couponViewModel.getCoupons();
        terms.clear();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for(int c=0;c<coupons.size();c++){
                    terms.addAll(termViewModel.getTermData(coupons.get(c).getRootTermId(),lastTermLayer));
                }
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(terms.size()>0){
                            noCouponText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            termsRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            termsRecyclerView.setAdapter(new LoadTermAdapter(terms,MainActivity.this));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

This is the code used to check for coupon that is already exists

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        final CouponViewModel couponViewModel= ViewModelProviders.of(EnterCoupon.this).get(CouponViewModel.class);
                        final boolean couponAlreadyUsed=couponViewModel.couponAlreadyUsed(key.getText().toString());
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if(couponAlreadyUsed){
                                    OkDialogue okDialogue=new OkDialogue();
                                    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                                    bundle.putString("content",getString(R.string.coupon_already_used));
                                    okDialogue.setArguments(bundle);
                                    okDialogue.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),getString(R.string.coupon_already_used));
                                    return;
                                }
}}
```

This is the code used to store data of the coupons

```
final CouponViewModel couponViewModel= ViewModelProviders.of(ChooseTerm.this).get(CouponViewModel.class);
                            final TermViewModel termViewModel= ViewModelProviders.of(ChooseTerm.this).get(TermViewModel.class);
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    if(p.connectionSucceed){
                                        try{
                                            JsonObject resultJson=JsonParser.parseString(p.postResult).getAsJsonObject();
                                            if(resultJson.get("result").getAsString().equals("success")){
                                                couponViewModel.addCoupon(coupon);

                                                Gson gson=new Gson();
                                                Type type=new TypeToken<List<TermEntity>>(){}.getType();
                                                List<TermEntity>termEntities=gson.fromJson(resultJson.get("terms").getAsJsonArray(),type);

                                                termViewModel.addTerms(termEntities);
                                                termViewModel.addTerms(chooseTermAdapter.checkedTerms);


                                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
                                                    finishAffinity();
                                                } else {
                                                    ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(ChooseTerm.this);
                                                }
                                                Intent intent=new Intent(ChooseTerm.this,MainActivity.class);
                                                startActivity(intent);
```

CouponViewModel.java

```
package sy.beta.viewmodel;

import android.app.Application;
import androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel;
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import java.util.List;

import sy.beta.db.AppRepository;
import sy.beta.db.entity.CouponEntity;


public class CouponViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private List<CouponEntity> coupons;
    private AppRepository repository;

    public CouponViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        repository = AppRepository.getInstance(application.getApplicationContext());
        coupons = repository.getAllCoupons();
    }

    public void addCoupon(CouponEntity coupon) {
        repository.addCoupon(coupon);
    }

    public List<CouponEntity> getCoupons() {
        coupons = repository.getCoupons();
        return coupons;
    }

    public boolean couponAlreadyUsed(String key) {
        return repository.couponAlreadyUsed(key);

    }
}
```

the AppRepository file

```
package sy.beta.db;

import android.content.Context;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import sy.beta.db.entity.CouponEntity;
import sy.beta.db.entity.TermEntity;


public class AppRepository {

    private List<CouponEntity> coupons;
    private List<TermEntity> terms;
    private QuizDatabase quizDb;
    private Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    private static AppRepository repoInstance;

    public static AppRepository getInstance(Context context) {
        if (repoInstance == null) {
            repoInstance = new AppRepository(context);
        }
        return repoInstance;
    }

    public List<CouponEntity> getCoupons() {
        return coupons;
    }

    public List<TermEntity> getTerms(){return terms;}

    private AppRepository(Context context) {
        quizDb = QuizDatabase.getInstance(context);
        coupons = getAllCoupons();
        terms=getAllTerms();
    }

    public List<CouponEntity> getAllCoupons() {
        return quizDb.couponDao().getAllCoupons();
    }

    public void addCoupon(final CouponEntity coupon) {
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                quizDb.couponDao().insertCoupon(coupon);
            }
        });
    }

    public List<TermEntity> getAllTerms(){
        return quizDb.termDao().getAllTerms();
    }

    public void addTerm(final TermEntity term){
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                quizDb.termDao().insertTerm(term);
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean couponAlreadyUsed(String key) {
        return quizDb.couponDao().couponAlreadyUsed(key);
    }

    public List<TermEntity> getTermData(int termId, int layer) {
        return quizDb.termDao().getTermData(termId,layer);
    }
}
```

the App database file

```
package sy.beta.db;


import android.content.Context;

import androidx.room.Database;
import androidx.room.Room;
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase;
import androidx.room.TypeConverters;

import sy.beta.db.converter.DateConverter;
import sy.beta.db.dao.CouponDao;
import sy.beta.db.dao.TermDao;
import sy.beta.db.entity.CouponEntity;
import sy.beta.db.entity.TermEntity;


@Database(entities = {CouponEntity.class, TermEntity.class}, version = 1,exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(DateConverter.class)
public abstract class QuizDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "QuizDatabase.db";

    private static volatile QuizDatabase quizDbInstance;
    private static final Object LOCK = new Object();

    public abstract CouponDao couponDao();
    public abstract TermDao termDao();

    public static QuizDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (quizDbInstance == null) {
            synchronized (LOCK) {
                if (quizDbInstance == null) {
                    quizDbInstance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                            QuizDatabase.class, DATABASE_NAME).build();
                }
            }
        }
        return quizDbInstance;
    }
}
```

I am sure that a litte trick can solve it but I can not figure it out

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out

The problem exists in the App Repository file;

In the the coupon is a List not a Live Data of list which means its value is not updated regularly unless the value of `AppRepository.getInstance()` and `repoInstance` is null  which refreshed the value of the list of coupons and that only happens when the app is force closed and opened again,

To resolve the problem there are two choices

change the code

```
public static AppRepository getInstance(Context context) {
        if (repoInstance == null) {
            repoInstance = new AppRepository(context);
        }
        return repoInstance;
    }
```

to

```
public static AppRepository getInstance(Context context) {
       //// if (repoInstance == null) {
            repoInstance = new AppRepository(context);
////        }
        return repoInstance;
    }
```

which refreshes the value of `repoInstance` and invokes the `AppRepository()` constructer regardless if the app is force closed or not

or I can change the code

```
public List<CouponEntity> getCoupons() {
        return coupons;
    }
```

to

```
public List<CouponEntity> getCoupons() {
        coupons=getAllCoupons();
        return coupons;
    }
```

and remove calling the `getAllCouponss()` from the `AppRepository` initialiser